# Java text formatter issues

Tags: java, list, text, linked-list, formatter

I'm working on some code that takes an input file and formats text. I only posted main of my code. I'm trying to find the maximum line length which is the code at the beginning of my else statement, it compiles and runs perfectly fine, but does not print out the "width", it seems like I have some sort of syntax problem or something that I can't seem to figure out. I've had a few people look at my code but with no success, does anyone here have any suggestions?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  int argix = 0;
  if (args.length == 0) {
    //There are no filenames given on the command line.
    out.printf ("FILE: -%n");
    format (new Scanner (in));  
  }else {
     // Iterate over each filename given on the command line.
     if(args[0].matches("-\\d+")){
       width=Integer.parseInt("-\\d+");
       width=width*-1;
       System.out.println(width);
       argix = 1;
     }
     for (; argix < args.length; ++argix) {
        String filename = args[argix];
        if (filename.equals ("-")) {
           // Treat a filename of "-" to mean System.in.
           out.printf ("FILE: -%n");
           format (new Scanner (in));
        }
        else {
           //Open the file and read it, or error out.
           try {
              Scanner infile = new Scanner (new File (filename));
              out.printf ("FILE: %s%n", filename);
              format (infile);
              infile.close();
           }catch (IOException error) {
              exit_status = EXIT_FAILURE;
              err.printf ("%s: %s%n", JAR_NAME,
                          error.getMessage());
           }
        }
     }
  }
  exit (exit_status);
```

}

Comment: Did you mean to write `parseInt(args[0])`?

Comment: Would that be the correct way to do it?

Comment: I attempted that, no change, still not printing out width

Comment: Please post the command line you are using to test your program.